# Display a message next to the textfield when the field loses focus in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4

How to display a message next to the `textfield` when the field loses focus after the value is entered. And when the field is empty no message should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `msgTarget` config of `textfield` to display the message or create custom `div` after `textfield` and assign your message to that `div` (by your coding).